# Edit Wordpress content in text editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem with editing HTML in the build in HTML editor. It adds paragraphs and reformats my code all the time. I would like to edit the content in an editor, like Sublime or VSCode.

I realize that the content is stored in the database, so I thought about using WP-CLI or a plugin to make this work. Or maybe a gulp task that somehow updates the database on file change (my HTML inputs). I haven't found anything like this online, so I'm asking you.

I cannot be alone with this problem? Another solution would be to replace the build in editor with something that doesn't suck. I tried 2 plugins, but they sucked even harder.

Ideas please? Professional wordpress coders should've figured this out?!

Comment: If you want to stop wordpress adding p tags into the content you need to remove built in filter with this code remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );

Comment: You can also add html content as a custom field value and output it without filtering anything. If that is an option for you.

Comment: Great tips Nick, something I will try. But I still would rather edit the code in an editor instead of the web editor. It's not color coded, no short commands works, no split view ie

Comment: You have a correct attitude. I cannot imagine writing code in any web based editor especially WordPress code editor. :)

Comment: If anyone hasn't solved this task, I might do it myself with Gulp and WP-CLI. Shouldn't take too long, but I would rather get started right away. Or maybe change platform.